# GNSS module's projection

Tags: python, c, math, gps, mathematical-optimization

How to compute the projection of a GNSS module at a height `h` with `x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw` data on a flat ground?

I searched online and couldn't find anything about how to handle such question.

Comment: Are you looking for trigonometric projection? What does GNSS have to do with it?

Comment: yes. GNSS is installed above a device at a height ```h = 3 m```. We record the device orientations and position ```x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw``` and I need to know the projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A place to start might be equation 1.78 in 'GPS for Geodesy' Edited by Kleugsberg and Teunissen which you can take a look at in pdfdrive.